# Ionic 2 app not woking on tablet

Tags: css, angular, ionic2

The app is working on mobile but trying to test on a **Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 inch** and it does not work. Inputs and button don't work, I can not do anything on the app.

Why would it work on mobile but not work on tablet?

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "ionic-app-base",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
    "serve:before": "watch",
    "emulate:before": "build",
    "deploy:before": "build",
    "build:before": "build",
    "run:before": "build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.37",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.0.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "lodash": "4.16.4",
    "moment": "^2.16.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "toastr": "^2.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.30",
    "typescript": "2.0.3"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-file",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer"
  ]
}
```

**Ionic Info:**

```
bash-3.2$ ionic info
--------------------------------
--------------------------------

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.30
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.9
OS: Mac OS X Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a

--------------------------------
```

**Background image CSS:**

```
ion-content {
    background: url('./../assets/images/abalobiTransparentBG.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
```

**Mobile:**

[image]

**Tablet:**

[image]

Comment: Its most likely your css background image overlay, can we see some css code ?